# Unable To Approve Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have app approval set up on SharePoint Online where users can request apps from the SharePoint store & they get approved or rejected by the App Catalog admin.

As an administrator I I am also presented with the "Request App" button. When I request an app the request appears as normal but the Approve / Reject button on the ribbon is greyed out.

I see a message when editing the approval request that says "app requests with this status cannot be approved or rejected".

I have SCA permission on the App Catalog site & on the site I'm trying to add the app to.

Is there something else that needs to be configured for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

This might be late but posting the solution in case someone else comes across this issue.

- Go to your SP Tenant Apps page: 
  https://*yourtenantname*-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/TenantAdminApps.aspx
- Click Purchase Apps
- Find the app that you want to add
- Click Add
  You can verify if the app was successfully added for all the users in your tenant by going to Manage licenses on Tenant Admin Apps page.